# How do i make http request from RabbitMQ message - nodejs

Tags: node.js, rabbitmq

```js
import * as Amqp from "amqp-ts";

const fetch = require('node-fetch');

let connection = new Amqp.Connection("amqp://admin:admin@localhost");
let exchange = connection.declareExchange("ExchangeName");
let queue = connection.declareQueue("nodejs");
queue.bind(exchange);
queue.activateConsumer(async (message) => {
  const site: string = message.getContent().site;
  console.log(site)
  const response = await fetch(site)
  console.log(response.status);
});
```

Pretty simple little snippet, the issue is that JS gets a message from RabbitMQ, then fires off a request and the gets a new message from RabbitMQ.

The issue is that it first gets all the messages and fires of all the requests, then tries to resolve them - so it just ends up taking all messages for it self.

What would be a good way (or just a way that would work) to set a max number of messages nodejs should be allowed to handle at any one time?

Answer (score 0):

```js
import * as Amqp from "amqp-ts";

const fetch = require('node-fetch');
const axios = require('axios')

let connection = new Amqp.Connection("amqp://admin:admin@localhost");
// let exchange = connection.declareExchange("ExchangeName");
let queue = connection.declareQueue("nodejs");
// queue.bind(exchange);

queue.prefetch(500);
queue.activateConsumer(async (message) => {
  const site: string = message.getContent().site;
  console.log(site)
  axios(site).then((response: any) => {
    console.log(response.status);
    message.ack();
  })
}).then(({consumerTag}) => {
  console.log(consumerTag)
});
```

So found an answer, the solution i found was first of all to acknowledge a successfull message comsumed

```
 message.ack();
```

and second to add a max allowed of messages in unacked

```
queue.prefetch(500);
```

This worked like a charm!